# Proving that an equation has a positive root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that an equation of the form $x^n = \alpha$, where $n \in N$, the set of Natural Numbers and $\alpha > 0$ is a real number has a positive root.

I am doing calculus in graduation. 
I tried to apply Mean Value theorems, but I couldn't. 
Please help me.

Comment: What function did you try the mean value theorem on?

Comment: I would think of the Intermediate Value Theorem here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha > 0$ be given and let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be given by $$f(x) = x^n - \alpha.$$ Then $f$ is polynomial, hence continuous. Moreover, $f(0) = - \alpha < 0$ and $$f(x) \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
It follows that there exists $K \in \mathbb R$, such that $f(x) > 1$ for all $x >K$. In particular, $f(K) \ge 1$. It follows by the intermediate value theorem that $f$ has a zero in the interval $(0,K)$.

This completes the proof.